# SQL Server Agent is stuck in Starting status

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Our SQL Agent server stopped working suddenly. We checked services and found that it got stuck in "Starting" status. We tried to restart by right click option but all `start`, `stop` and `restart` options are disabled (displaying grey). We checked Sql Agent server logs.

**SQLAgent.OUT has following :**

> SQLSERVERAGENT service stopping due to a stop request from a user,
>   process, or the OS... Scheduler engine timed out (after 15 seconds)
>   waiting for 80 jobs to stop SQLServerAgent terminated (forcefully)

So please help us what should we do except rebooting the machine (We want to avoid reboot machine as it's production server).

Comment: Do you see a sqlagent.exe process? Maybe try to kill it, start again and check the logs.

Comment: kill the `sqlagent.exe` in the task manager and start the agent again

Comment: Thanks Kirchner & Krismorte, there is no sqlagent.exe in the task manager. I think that comes in the task manager when our service is running but that's not the case at my end. Sql Agent server got stuck into "Starting" status. I can see SQLAGENT$SERVERNAME in Services tab of task manager when i click on "Go to Details" of this services, it takes me to "System Idle process" of processes tab.End task is disabled for this process so we can't kill this.